# MySQL: How to use OR between 2 different values in WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in database with the name `module`, and I want the `SELECT` statement to show all values that has `delete_time` with either `NULL` or `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. I used the following statement, but it did not work.
The statement is:

```
$statment="SELECT * FROM module where delete_time IS NULL OR delete_time IS '0000-00-00 00:00:00 '";
```

Comment: What do you mean didn't work? Is there an error, or does the query not select rows that you expect? What is your table structure? Ie what data type is `delete_time`?

Comment: it did not show any data that has either  NULL value or the 0000-00-00 00:00:00 and the data type is datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

- You've got an extra space at the end of your quoted date time string `'0000-00-00 00:00:00 '`
- Don't use `IS` to compare `delete_time` to `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`.  `IS` is to compare against boolean values or `NULL`.  Use `=` instead.

Try this:

```
     $statment="SELECT * FROM module where delete_time IS NULL OR delete_time = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'";
```

Comment: thanks, i checked it like many time but could not see that space, no it works

Comment: @georgeabousaydeh I hope no is *now! :P